# Is it possible to extend the C: drive to the left?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I read that if I extend the C: drive partition to the left, the boot will get corrupted. Is there any way to do it without hurting the boot?

Here is a screenshot of my Disk Management screen for clarification:

[image]

Comment: Extending to the left is not clear, can you post an image of your partitions and exactly which ones you want to grow and/or shrink?

Comment: OK, I added an image

Comment: You have to move it to left and extend to the right. Try `gparted`.

Comment: @arminb but if I move it to the left, the boot won't get corrupted?

Comment: Yes, it will. In this case the easiest way to fix it is to boot a windows installation from DVD or USB stick and select the repair option. This can be scary the first time, but it always worked for me.

Comment: @arminb Thank you. Forgot to include that myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Be careful.**

This looks like a dual-boot system. It is possible that the 9.77 GB partition that Windows thinks is empty is actually an important partition for the other OS.
Windows has a nasty habit of identifying stuff it doesn't recognize as "empty".

Get a copy of **[GParted](http://gparted.org)**. This is small Linux-based partition utility that runs from a CD or USB stick. It knows about any partitioning system and filesystem that you are likely to encounter in the wild, more or lses. It is extremely reliable.

[image]

If GParted also thinks it is empty you can use GParted to modify the disk. It is technically not possible to extend most filesystems to the left, so it needs to be done in two steps:

- Move the C: drive to the left (which will take a while)
- Extend it to cover the free space to the right, which is very quick.

After that it is possible your MBR won't find the moved partition anymore. The easiest way to fix this is to boot a windows installation from DVD or USB stick and select the repair option. That should fix the MBR issue.

---

*Be warned: Gparted.com is a somewhat dubious website unrelated to Gparted.org. Make sure you get your copy from the correct website!*

Comment: I'm sure it's empty, because I made it

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that Knoppix has gparted included.  It's not in the GUI menu, but you can run it from a terminal.

Comment: Gparted is included in most modern distros. However it's very slow compared to [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html) or [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), or commercial tools like Acronis disk director because it doesn't move data in a smart way whereas other tools just move the needed sectors. It's also bad in many ways like doesn't automatically manage extended partitions, requiring you to resize the extended partition separately before doing related things

Comment: To whoever added the picture and reformatted my answer: Thank you! Much better.

Comment: @Tonny no problem!